# Spark DataFrame - Get the average of two column combinations

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How I get the average of Price for each combination of 2 columns?

My DataFrame:

```
relevantTable = df.select(df['Price'], df['B'], df['A'])
```

looks like:

```
+-------+------------+------------------+
|  Price|     B      |          A       |
+-------+------------+------------------+
| 0.2947|   i3.xlarge|                 x|
|  0.105|    c4.large|                 x|
| 0.2179|   m4.xlarge|                 x|
| 2.2534| m4.10xlarge|                 x|
| 2.1801| m4.10xlarge|                 x|
|  0.108|    r4.large|                 x|
|  0.108|    r4.large|                 x|
| 0.0213|    i3.large|                 y|
| 0.5572|  i2.4xlarge|                 y|
| 0.1542|  c4.4xlarge|                 y|
| 0.3624| m4.10xlarge|                 y|
| 0.3596| m4.10xlarge|                 y|
|   0.11|    m4.large|                 x|
| 0.4436|  m4.2xlarge|                 x|
| 0.1458|  m4.2xlarge|                 y|

... and so on real huge set
```

What would be a simple and scalable solution to get the average for all combinations of **A** and **B**?

Comment: So what I tried was .reduce and .reduceByKey but I think I do something wrong here :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
df.groupBy("A", "B").avg("Price")
```

or if you want to include aggregates by single column:

```
df.cube("A", "B").avg("Price")
```

Comment: Wow this is to easy... damn I have to learn much more about this framework. Thank you very much!